# Removing Withheld points from a LAS file with a PDAL pipeline

Tags: classification, las, pdal

I'm currently rewriting a system that batch processes lots of LAS/LAZ files. The heavy lifting is in C++/CUDA, but I'm currently working on a preprocessor that downloads the lidar files, finds their bounding boxes and reprojects them. As it is a rewrite, we are already aware of some of the potential issues these files can have, eg. data points outside of the header's bounding box; points classified as 'noise'; and points marked as 'withheld' (ie. ready for delete).

The preprocessor is a mixture of Python and a PDAL pipeline. It is easy enough to filter noise and out-of-range points.  But how can I filter the "withheld" points?

In the original (pre-rewrite) C++/CUDA code, these are filtered when the data points are loaded. And I can still do this, but each imported lidar file will typically be read multiple times, so it makes sense to filter all bad data points in the preprocessor.

Here is the existing C++ code which skips the current point (point index `idx`) if it is marked as withheld:

```
const int LAS_CLASS_BIT_WITHHELD = 0x80; // LAS v1.0-1.3
const int LAS_CLASSFLAG_BIT_WITHHELD = 0x04;  // LAS v1.4 and later

// ClassFlags only supported in LAS v1.4 and later
classflags = point_view->getFieldAs<int>(pdal::Dimension::Id::ClassFlags, idx);
if ( (classflags & LAS_CLASSFLAG_BIT_WITHHELD) != 0)
    continue;

int classification = point_view->getFieldAs<int>(pdal::Dimension::Id::Classification, idx);
if (minorVersion < 4  &&    (classification & LAS_CLASS_BIT_WITHHELD) != 0  )
    continue;
```

As you can see, the definition of 'withheld' is not simple and is dependent on the LAS format's minor version.

So is it possible to filter these? Finding the minor version is easy enough, but I can't find a way to apply a bit mask on a dimension.